# How to add link to part of component and make clickable

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a File component and I'm rendering the name of the file and want to attach a link to it

```
if (item.type === "file") {
      return (
      <File name={item.name}  /> // want to attach URL(item.url) to this item.name
      
      );
    }
```

and I want to attach URL to the file and make it clickable

Comment: could you explain more what you want

Comment: Wrap it with `<a>` tag.

Comment: @Joseph I have made a File component and I'm rendering its name and I want to attach a url link to that name so that i can click and name of the file and open it

Comment: You can us the <Link> Tag

Answer (score 0):

I'd do this:

```js
item.type === "file" &&(
      <Link to={`/${item.url}`}>
      <File name={item.name} /> 
      </Link>
      );
```